# aws push notifications for multiple devices

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I am using aws sns for sending push notifications to devices(mobile devices mostly android). I am able to send notifications to individual devices but i want to publish a common message that has to be sent to all the active devices. I have created platform application and created the end points using all the device registration ids and also created the topic and subscribed to it but when i publish the message, the publish is success and i get the message id but i am not getting the notifications. I have implemented most of the methods which are in AmazonSNSClient class. If someone can guide me it would be very helpful.

Comment: In the topic description, are you able to see all the subscriptions?

Comment: yes . I am able to see all subscriptions also i am getting the message id after publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the aws console in the website using your credentials there you will find details of the notifications sent. If you find that the notification is sent then probably the notification has failed. AWS does not guarantee the delivery of notifications.